# MaterialDatePicker Select Date between 2 dates only

Tags: android, kotlin, android-datepicker, material-components-android

How to add a constraint to MaterialDatePicker to force user to select a date between only 2 dates?

```
val constraintBuilder = CalendarConstraints.Builder()
    val materialRangeBuilder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
    materialRangeBuilder.setTitleText("Book Date")
    materialRangeBuilder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintBuilder.build())

    val materialRangePicker = materialRangeBuilder.build()

    materialRangePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
        Timber.d("$it")
    }

    materialRangePicker.show(supportFragmentManager, "DATE_RANGE_PICKER")
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a **`DateValidator`** to restrict the selections.
In particular you can use the built-in validators:

- **`DateValidatorPointForward`**  that enables dates from a given point forward
- **`DateValidatorPointBackward`** that enables only dates before a given point.

Something like:

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();

CalendarConstraints.Builder constraintsBuilderRange = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();

//....define min and max for example with LocalDateTime and ZonedDateTime or Calendar

CalendarConstraints.DateValidator dateValidatorMin = DateValidatorPointForward.from(min.getTimeInMillis());
CalendarConstraints.DateValidator dateValidatorMax = DateValidatorPointBackward.before(max.getTimeInMillis());

ArrayList<CalendarConstraints.DateValidator> listValidators =
            new ArrayList<CalendarConstraints.DateValidator>();
listValidators.add(dateValidatorMin);
listValidators.add(dateValidatorMax);
CalendarConstraints.DateValidator validators = CompositeDateValidator.allOf(listValidators);
constraintsBuilderRange.setValidator(validators);

builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilderRange.build());

MaterialDatePicker<Long> picker = builder.build();
picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), picker.toString());
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @AhmedAbdeen You can also build your custom `DateValidator` overriding the  `isValid(date: Long)` method.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti what if I want to limit it from year? Example oldest year is 2009 up to current year for example?

Answer (score 6):

This is version for kotlin :

```
private fun calendarConstraints(): CalendarConstraints {
    val dateValidatorMin: DateValidator = DateValidatorPointForward.from(min.getTimeInMillis())
    val dateValidatorMax: DateValidator = DateValidatorPointBackward.before(max.getTimeInMillis())

    val listValidators = ArrayList<DateValidator>()
    listValidators.apply {
        add(dateValidatorMin)
        add(dateValidatorMax)
    }
    val validators = CompositeDateValidator.allOf(listValidators)

    return CalendarConstraints.Builder()
        .setValidator(validators)
        .build()
}
private fun setupCalendar() {
   val materialDatePickerBuilder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker().setCalendarConstraints(calendarConstraints())}
```

Answer (score 3):

@GabrieleMariotti answer is good, but DateValidatorPointBackwards class is not in material design library before version 1.2. If you want to choose between two dates and you have material design library version 1.1 or earlier, you can do it like this:

```
val datePickerBuilder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
datePickerBuilder.setCalendarConstraints(
    CalendarConstraints.Builder()
        .setValidator(object : CalendarConstraints.DateValidator {
            override fun isValid(date: Long): Boolean {
                return date >= startDate && date < endDate
            }

            override fun writeToParcel(p0: Parcel?, p1: Int) {}

            override fun describeContents(): Int {return 0}
        }).build()
)
val datePicker = datePickerBuilder.build()
datePicker!!.show(fragmentManager, "date picker")
```

where startDate and endDate are long values

Answer (score 0):

update build.gradle (app) version as below

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

code level

```
CalendarConstraints.Builder constraintsBuilderRange = new CalendarConstraints.Builder()
                .setValidator(DateValidatorPointBackward.now());
        builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilderRange.build());
        MaterialDatePicker picker = builder.build();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use these two methods

```
public void setMinDate (long minDate)
public void setMaxDate (long maxDate)
```

Here is the official documentation.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker#setMaxDate(long)

Example

```
val calender = Calendar.getInstance()
val year = calender.get(Calendar.YEAR)
val month = calender.get(Calendar.MONTH)
val day = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
materialRangeBuilder.setMinDate(calender.getTimeInMillis())
materialRangeBuilder.setMaxDate(calender.getTimeInMillis())
```

Comment: That's for the Android platform version of the datepicker.

Comment: setMinDate and setMaxDate isn't available in material design range object