# DateValidatorPointBackward not found

Tags: java, android, kotlin, material-design

I wanted to set some `CalendarConstraints` I cant select past dates

```
 val dateValidatorMax: DateValidator =
                DateValidatorPointForward.now();
            val dateValidatorMin: DateValidator =
                DateValidatorPointBackward.before(selectedStartDateInMillis)

            val constraintsBuilder =
                CalendarConstraints.Builder()
                    .setValidator(dateValidatorMax).build()

            val picker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
                .setSelection(dateRange).setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder)
                .setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialCalendar);


            picker.build().apply {
                addOnPositiveButtonClickListener { selectedDateRangePair ->
                    onDateRangeSelected(
                        selectedDateRangePair
                    )
                }
            }.show(
                requireActivity().supportFragmentManager,
                MaterialDatePicker::class.java.canonicalName
            )
```

Everything is Working fine but im getting this error `Unresolved reference: DateValidatorPointBackward`

[StackoverFlowLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62469312/materialdatepicker-select-date-between-2-dates-only) i saw this `DateValidatorPointForward` is ok but im showing error in `DateValidatorPointBackward`
[image: suggestion]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Try to update version of material dependency to 1.2.0 or greater in build.gradle(app)

```
com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0
```